# header () call not going where defined

Tags: php

I have an icon which is surrounded by anchor tags in an echo statement:

```
<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=$thought_id'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' aria-hidden='true' style='padding-right: 5px;'></span> 
</a>
```

When this icon is clicked, I need it to perform a PHP query which is found in `favourite_post.php`.

Here is `favourite_post.php` :

```
$getid = $_GET['id'];
$favourited_by = $username;
/***********************/
//query to get user id
$get_uid = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
while($query = mysqli_fetch_array($get_uid)){
    $uid = $query['id'];
}
/***********************/
// get details of the post id and username
$get_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by ='$user'");
$row_query = mysqli_fetch_array($get_id);
$fav_by = $row_query['favourited_by'];
$fav_status = $row_query['fav_status'];

$fav_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO post_favourites (user_id, thought_id) VALUES ('$uid', '$getid')");

header ("Location: ../profile_page/$added_by");
```

**Problem walk through:**

1. Assume I am logged in as Alice and I am on andersons `profile_page`. The URL at this point will read `http://localhost/profile_page/anderson`.
2. I like a post from `Anderson` and click the icon, which performs this query to favourite their post.
3. When a user favourites someone's post, I need the page's location to be on the same address, i.e. stay on `http://localhost/profile_page/anderson`. So in the `header()` call, I have specified it's location to be `../profile_page/$added_by`. `$added_by` is the username of the user and should take the user back to `http://localhost/profile_page/anderson`, but it doesn't.
4. When the icon is clicked, the address bar reads `http://localhost/profile_page/` .. meaning the `$added_by` variable is not being passed through.

**Edit**:

Here is where I have defined `$added_by`:

```
$get_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by ='$user'");
    $row_query = mysqli_fetch_array($get_id);
        $added_by = $row_query['added_by'];
        $fav_by = $row_query['favourited_by'];
        $fav_status = $row_query['fav_status'];
```

I have previously used `header ("Location: profile_page/$user")` on other pages. `$user` is the var which holds the data after `?u=` in the URL. `$added_by` obtains the same data from the data. `$user` and `$added_by` are both usernames for users, which is why I am stumped.

Comment: You never define `$added_by`.

Comment: check if you're not outputting before header. either way, that header is failing for a reason or two, maybe even the variable failed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: curious how this is used `<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=$thought_id'>` is that inside PHP tags at all? I almost posted an answer, but afraid it would have backfired on me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, sorry, should have specified, the above is in an echo statement.

Comment: oh there you are. well I submitted an answer which I may as well delete now. Edit: answer deleted

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Don't know how I missed that! Nevertheless, I have defined it now, but still have the same issue.

Comment: Are there any "Headers already sent" warnings in the PHP log?

Comment: @Fred-ii- My apologies, I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: @Barmar - No. No warnings of the sort.

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you're setting `$added_by`?

Comment: *"stores the `$username` variable which is the session"* - as in `$_SESSION`? if so, did you start the session and inside all pages using them?

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yes,for the pages involved,  the `$_SESSION` is found on both `profile_page.php` and on `favourite_post.php` and session_start() has been used on both.

Comment: what I don't get is where `$favourited_by` is defined and the same for `$user` and `$thought_id` something doesn't add up here. Are you 100% sure you're using error reporting? You're also not checking for errors for your queries. There isn't anything else I can think of here other than adding `exit;` to header if there's any more code below that. Use `var_dump();` to see what's going through or not and scattered echo'd variables.

Comment: *"which holds the data after `?u=` in the URL"* - and you're using `?id=$thought_id` what am I not getting here too. `?u` and `?id`. That doesn't add up here.

Comment: ping me if I got anything right. I have to leave the question now, I did my best to help out. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually meant to use the `$favourited_by` variable in your `header()` call:

```
header( "Location: ../profile_page/$favourited_by" );
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. The `$favourited_by` variable stores the `$username` variable which is the session created for the logged in user. With that header() call, I will always be redirected to the logged in users `profile_page`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is invalid: `<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=$thought_id'>`.  It should be like this: `<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=<?php echo $thought_id;?>'>`.  Of course, I assumed '$thought_id' is a php variable.